# How to provide a route for current user in a REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

So I have a simple `users` resource defined in my routes.

```
resources :users
```

I need to provide a route so that a logged in user can get his information in the front end. I thought about doing this:

```
resources :users do
  get 'current' , on: :collection
end
```

But this semantically means that the route gives a list of current **users**, not the current **user**. And Indeed if I do `rake routes`, it shows the path prefix as: `current_users`

I can work around the path prefix by doing something like this:

```
get '/users/current' => 'users#current', as: 'current_user'
```

But this still looks like it provides a list of users. So, I was wondering if there was a 'right way' to do this kind of thing and how to do it in rails? Or am I thinking too much about this and what I have is fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if there was a 'right way'

The "right" way is to use a [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :user #-> url.com/user -> users#show
```

---

Of course, the "right" way implies there is a "wrong" way, which is not the case.

Programming is one of the few practices where you can do whatever you want, so long as the result is achieved. Of course, *how* you achieve that result can be criticized; ultimately, there are a myriad of ways to achieve it...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  get :current, on: :collection #-> url.com/users/current -> users#current
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def current
      @user = current_user
   end
end
```

The above (your code) does what my code does, just in a different way.

Just because you're using a [*collection*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) route, doesn't mean you need to pass a collection. The "collection" route is mainly for Rails routing structures; the routes have no bearing on your backend code.

--

This also means you should be willing to experiment with options / switches to customize your routing:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :user, path: "current_user", as: :current_user #-> url.com/current_user -> users#show
```

Comment: Thank you, just a small question: in the last example if you don't specify the controller it defaults to `users`. So I have to manually detect in the `show` action (for example) whether this is a request to `/current_user` or to `/users/:id` by checking `params[:id]`. correct?

Answer (score 2):

> 2.5 Singular Resources Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like
>   /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user.
>   In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather
>   than /profile/:id) to the show action: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

maybe you meant it?

```
resource :user
```

Answer (score 1):

Singular Resources as [henb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3267305/henb) noted are what you're looking for. Or this:

```
get 'user/current' => 'users#current', as :current_user
```

One thing I've done is use the singular form in the resources statement because the actions dealt with individual users (eg. /usr/573 to display the information for user 573), then added an extra match for the list of all users:

```
match 'users' => 'user#index', as :user_list, via: [ :get, :post ]
get 'user/current' => 'user#current', as :current_user
resources :user, except: :index
```

Not precisely RESTful, but it made the URLs reflect accurately whether I was dealing with the set of users vs. an individual user. The :post for the user list is for the search box submission.